# Combine search for characters in two columns

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

The script below seems to work fine. It does what I want it to do. However, I am sure there is a better, tidier more succinct way to write it.

Essentially, the script looks in a column to find if certain characters are in that column. If they are it runs a function `ageCategories()`. If not it looks in a different column for the same characters and if they exist there it runs the same function `ageCategories()`.

If none of the characters exists in either column it runs a different function first `genderMatch()` and then runs `ageCategories()`.

```
{
    var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    var column = sh.getRange("Imported!E2:E50").getValues();

    var values = column.reduce(function(accumulator, currentValue) {
        return accumulator.concat(currentValue);
    }, []);

    var containsKey = values.some(function(value) {
        return /[MWFmwf]/.test(value);
    });

    if (containsKey) {
        ageCategories();
    } else {
        var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
        var column = sh.getRange("Imported!I2:I50").getValues();

        var values = column.reduce(function(accumulator, currentValue) {
            return accumulator.concat(currentValue);
        }, []);

        var containsKey = values.some(function(value) {
            return /[MWFmwf]/.test(value);
        });

        if (containsKey) {
            ageCategories();
        } else {
            genderMatch();
            SpreadsheetApp.flush();
            ageCategories();
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone make this better than it is please. Most grateful.

Comment: Its syntax is currently invalid. Your 3rd line is `}` with no matching `{`, and the standalone `{` on line 5 is *really* weird (though permitted in ES6... is GAS even ES6 compatible?) If your code works, you should ask Code Review, it's not a good fit for Stack Overflow. You should also consider indenting in a consistent manner, it'll make code a lot more readable

Comment: It does not work fine. It throws exceptions due to invalid JavaScript Syntax.

Comment: I'll re-iterate the first two comments as you seem to be ignoring them. The code you posted appears invalid due at least to the first two lines you posted

Comment: Apologies, first two lines deleted.

Comment: The code is incomplete (`function functionName()` is missing and who knows what else)

Comment: @Rubén - do you expect to see every single line of javascript the OP has? the code is not incomplete, it has all the necessary parts to answer the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DRY (don't repeat yourself) code version looks like

```
var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

var containsKey = function(range) {
    var column = sh.getRange(range).getValues();
    var values = column.reduce(function (accumulator, currentValue) {
        return accumulator.concat(currentValue);
    }, []);
    return values.some(function (value) { return /[MWFmwf]/.test(value); });
}

if (!(containsKey("Imported!E2:E50") || containsKey("Imported!I2:I50"))) {
    genderMatch();
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}
ageCategories();
```

If you want more than two ranges to check

```
var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

var containsKey = function(range) {
    var column = sh.getRange(range).getValues();
    var values = column.reduce(function (accumulator, currentValue) {
        return accumulator.concat(currentValue);
    }, []);
    return values.some(function (value) { return /[MWFmwf]/.test(value); });
}

var ranges = ["Imported!E2:E50", "Imported!I2:I50"];
if (!ranges.some(containsKey)) {
    genderMatch();
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}
ageCategories();
```

Though can be even more succinct using ES6+ syntax - but as per comment below *Google Apps Script doesn't support ES6+ by default* so this may be redundant

ES6+ version, includes code that would allow more than 2 ranges to be checked for the key (not sure that's relevant to this code, but may be useful for similar situations)

```
const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

const containsKey = range => sh.getRange(range).getValues().flat().some(value => /[MWFmwf]/.test(value));

const ranges = ["Imported!E2:E50", "Imported!I2:I50"]; // allows more than two ranges if that's likely to happen
if (!ranges.some(containsKey)) {
    genderMatch();
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}
ageCategories();
```

Comment: That's a vast improvement on the OP's code. You should consider posting the ES6+ version as well, just so it's there.

Comment: @JackBashford - was going to until I saw the downvote :p

Comment: Bear in mind that Google Apps Script doesn't support ES6+ by default as well it doesn't support calling functions on the global scope.

Comment: OK, well then, I'll remove that - I suspected as much anyway

Comment: Thank you very much anyway @JaromandaX The first code is splendid.

Comment: @StephenCousins - I've added an ES5 version that could be a little more useful especially if you have more than two ranges to "check"

Comment: Much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for that answer.  I'm still a little weak in some of the array methods and I enjoyed learning a bit more about reduce and some.